# Adding Segment telemtry to React component that is only one DOM node

Tags: reactjs, jupyter, analytics, jupyter-lab, segment-analytics

I'm looking to add [segment](https://segment.com/) analytics to my JupyterLab extension. No worries if you've never heard of a JupyterLab extension - the best way to think about it: I get control over a single node in the DOM where I can place some HTML, so I'm doing the following:

```
function Welcome(props) {return <h1>Hello</h1>;}
ReactDOM.render(<Welcome/>, dom_element_i_control)
```

This all works fine - I'm now looking to add some analytics code to this. For example, I'd like to be able to:

1. See when my code is rendered
2. See when someone interacts with my rendered element (e.g. if there was a button in the Welcome function, when the user clicked on it).

However, segment is a JS library that is delivered as a script that you load into a webpage at the top in a string tag like:

```
<script>
  !function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&...}}();
</script>
```

Where would I even put this code? I don't have control over the larger page + HTML, so I'm not sure where I can slap this so I can start using analytics.

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

1. Instead of using the above linked segment script, I used the `analytics-node` package from segment.
2. I create an `Analytics` object right before `ReactDOM.render` - and then can use it wherever I want :)

Note that this will not work for anyone who uses an add blocker, obviously!